# Typescript: Return a reference object that can be assigned to?

Tags: typescript, return-value, variable-assignment

I have an existing set of classes that have a number of spots where they get, and one spot where they set, a named property from an array, i.e.

```
return object[index];
// or
object[index] = newValue;
```

Due to one existing module that does things differently than everywhere else, I have had to update these to take a function that can optionally define alternate ways to get at the appropriate value:

```
varAccessFunction: (obj: T, index: string) => any
// For example:
varAccessFunction = (obj: { [key: string]: AbstractControl; }, index: string): any => obj[myFields.find(item => item.variableName === index)?.displayName!].value;
```

After rewiring all the classes to take the getter, I absentmindedly tried to use it for the setter as well, and got the error: `The left-hand side of an assignment expression must be a variable or a property access.` Well, okay, yeah, I obviously can't assign a value to a value. So I'm going to have to go back through the layers and thread all the constructors with a `set`  function to match the `get` function, in order to use a nearly identical expression in exactly one place.

Unless.

Is there a way to specify this function to return a reference value that can be assigned to? It would be so easy in C++ or something to return an explicit reference, but in Typescript, the values are all going to be primitives, which are value types. I'm not seeing a way to return a reference to a primitive in Typescript, but maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Typescript = Javascript + type annotations. If you can't do it in Javascript then you can't do it in Typescript either.

Answer (score 0):

There is no sense of "reference values" built into JavaScript. Frameworks like Vue introduce their own concepts of [refs](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/refs-api.html#ref) which wrap a possibly-primitive value to track and propagate its "get" and "set" actions.

This would be easy to expose as a class with `get` and `set` methods, where `get` implements your `varAccessFunction` with multiple parameters and `set` does the opposite. Like Vue, you could also implement this with [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) functions that represent the interface as a value property (possibly named "value"); presumably you'd take your index in a `varAccessFunction` and return a quasi-reference that knows how to get and set its value back to its actual source of truth.

This is not quite what you're looking for, since you'd still have to define an object and use some kind of dot-accessed property for JavaScript to dispatch your custom setter, but other than the necessary `.value` (etc) you'd get reference-like behavior without additional frameworks or cleverness.

This also falls back to a simple `{ value: "foo" }` object as its minimal fake implementation, which might be helpful for unit testing.